# Flask - Call a route and the go back to the first route

Tags: python, redirect, flask

In my app, I have a route called /main.  I also have a route called /index which checks to see if a session token has expired.  If it has, it calls /login.  If not, it goes back to /main.

This is so that if someone refreshes /main then it will check their session status first.

What I'd like to do at the start of /main is call /index.  Then, at the end of /index go back to /main and continue from where it left off rather than starting the route again.

So, something like:

```
@app.route('/main')
   return redirect(url_for('index'))
   #Do the /main stuff

@app.route('index')
   #Do some stuff
   return redirect(url_for('main')) #But don't go back to the start, go back to doing the /main stuff
```

Obviously, this will just get me into an endless loop.  Could someone suggest the proper method to achieve this.

Comment: Have a look at this https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: I'm using the Hive API.  I send it some JSON to login and it gives me a token. I send the token if I want to do something like turn a light on. I'm storing the token in a session variable so that I can pass it from route to route.

So, my /index route looks to see if the session variable exists.  If no, it goes to the /login route.  If yes, it sends a quick query to see if the token is valid by looking for errors in the response.  If error -> /login.  If no error -> /main.I think there's a difference between what I'm doing and creating something to authenticate users within my app.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite what you're requesting, but have you considered having your check done outside of a route and calling it when needed in your routes? Something like this is what I have set up --

```py
class User(object):
    def __init__(self, current_user=None, option=None):
        self.current_user = current_user
        self.option = option

    def do_checks(self):
        self.current_user = request.remote_user
        option_val = request.cookies.get('option')
        if option_val is None:
            self.option = None
        else:
            self.option = option_val

@app.route('/route/', methods=['GET'])
def myroute():
    user = User()
    user.do_checks()

    if user.option is None:
        return redirect(url_for('login'))

    ## code..
```

Or maybe look into setting up decorators for your routes, similar to Flask-Login, to lock certain routes only to those who are already authorized:

```py
@app.route('/post')
@login_required
def post():
    pass
```

```py
if not current_user.is_authenticated:
    return current_app.login_manager.unauthorized()
```

[Flask-Login — Flask-Login 0.4.1 documentation](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#flask_login.login_required)